# How to copy binary data from one stream to another?

Tags: c++, binary, stream

Currently i have a program that loads binary data into a stringstream and then pases the data to a fstream like so:

```
stringstream ss(stringstream::binary | stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
ss.write(data, 512);  // Loads data into stream

// Uses a memory block to pass the data between the streams
char* memBlock = new char[512];
ss.read(memBlock, 512);

ofstream fout("someFile.bin", ios::binary);
fout.write(memBlock, 512);  // Writes the data to a file
fout.close();

delete[] memBlock;
```

My question is: is there a better way to pass the binary data between the streams?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the [`streambuf`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/) members, that's what they are for:

```
fout << ss.rdbuf();
```

Comment: Isn´t "operator<<" for formated input? i´m working with binary data.

Comment: @Fabi1816: There is an overload for `streambuf` which does binary output. This overload is here to do exactly what you request here.

Comment: This is functionally correct. I've found copying data with C++ streams to be 2-3 times slower than using the C style methods posted above. Much to my annoyance.

Comment: Also, the entire stream is copied. Sometimes one needs to copy data from a certain offset and/or a certain amount of bytes only.

Comment: OMG, that operator copies the data from the input stream byte by byte... At least in the STL shipped by Microsoft

Comment: Another issue is if the input stream is empty, then the `failbit` is raised in the output stream