# How to create a folder in c++ in a more efficient way?

Tags: c++, directory

In my C++ project I have provided an option to take a backup of the files that are created to store the records, which takes the backup of files in a user given path by creating a folder in that Directory. The code for the same is as follows:

```
void backup()
{
 char a[40],c[40],b[40];
 product p1;
 clrscr();
 ifstream fp1("products.dat", ios::binary);
 ifstream fp2("purchase.dat",ios::binary);
 ifstream fp3("sales.dat",ios::binary);
 if(fp1==NULL || fp2==NULL || fp3==NULL)
 {
  cout<<"\n\tError-No or Incomplete Database...";
 }
 else
 {
  cout<<d_line;
  cout<<"\t\t\t       Database backup";
  cout<<"\n\t\t\t       -------- ------";
  cout<<line;
  cout<<"\n\tEnter the Directory in which you want to create backup:";
  gets(a);
  strcpy(b,a);
  strcpy(c,a);
  strcat(a,"/backup_b");
  strcat(b,"/backup_b");
  strcat(c,"/backup_b");
  mkdir(a);
  strcat(a,"/products.dat");
  strcat(b,"/purchase.dat");
  strcat(c,"/sales.dat");
  ofstream fp1_t(a, ios::binary | ios::trunc);
  ofstream fp2_t(b, ios::binary | ios::trunc);
  ofstream fp3_t(c, ios::binary | ios::trunc);

  if(fp1_t==NULL || fp2_t==NULL ||fp3_t==NULL)
  {
   cout<<"\n\n\tError During creating backup...\n";
  }
  else
  {
   while(!fp1.eof())
   {
    fp1.read((char *) &p1,sizeof(struct product));
    if(fp1.fail())
    {
     break;
    }
    else
    {
     fp1_t.write((char *) &p1,sizeof(struct product));
    }
   }
   while(!fp2.eof())
   {
    fp2.read((char *) &p1,sizeof(struct product));
    if(fp2.fail())
    {
     break;
    }
    else
    {
     fp2_t.write((char *) &p1,sizeof(struct product));
    }
   }
   while(!fp3.eof())
   {
    fp3.read((char *) &p1,sizeof(struct product));
    if(fp3.fail())
    {
     break;
    }
    else
    {
     fp3_t.write((char *) &p1,sizeof(struct product));
    }
   }
   fp1_t.close();
   fp2_t.close();
   fp3_t.close();
  }
  fp1.close();
  fp2.close();
  fp3.close();
  cout<<line;
  cout<<"\n\tBackup Created Successfully...";
 }
 cout<<line<<conti;
 getch();
}
```

**I want to know, is there a more efficient way to create a folder in C++ than what I am doing?**

Comment: What operating system are you using? What do you mean by _"more efficient"_? General point of style, if you're using C++, use `std::string` and avoid the C-string manipulation functions like `strcat`.

Comment: And how are you creating a dir in the first place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to copy binary data from one stream to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738233/how-to-copy-binary-data-from-one-stream-to-another)

Comment: `mkdir()` creates the folder, and you won't get more 'efficient' than that. I'm guessing it's writing your 'backup file' that's concerning you. See the 'duplicate' question above, maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there are certainly more platform-independent ways of doing this, and more type-safe ways. Try [boost filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows, then `CreateDirectory` is the simplest option.
Here's an example:

```
#include "Windows.h"
...
    CreateDirectory("C:\\temp\\sampledir", NULL);
...
```

It's part of the Windows API, documented here: [MSDN entry for CreateDirectory function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I'd love to know how that's more 'efficient' (or even simpler) than `mkdir()`.

Comment: Isn't mkdir() in sys/stat.h, which is not ANSI/ISO/C99 standard (i.e. compiler-spesific)?

Answer (score 0):

I always use the following function to create a folder. I use this because, for one thing, I don't want to use any 3rd-party library like `boost`; and at the same time, simply calling WIN32 API `CreateDirectory()` is not smart enough which lets us create a directory, but it works only when the parent directory already exists. This function overcomes this limitation. For example, it can create a folder named `test` by passing in './subfolder/test' even folder `subfolder` doesn't exist. Moreover, if the folder already exists, it is left unaffected, but if it doesn't exist, it is created.

```
void create_directory(char* Path)
{
    char DirName[256];
    char* p = Path;
    char* q = DirName;  

    while(*p)
    {
        if (('\\' == *p) || ('/' == *p))
        {
            if (':' != *(p-1))
            {
                CreateDirectory(DirName, NULL);
            }
        }
        *q++ = *p++;
        *q = '\0';
    }
    CreateDirectory(DirName, NULL);
}
```